# Can someone tell me what the enter key is in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
firmware = input("which image would you like to upload?")
if firmware == 1:
    net_connect.send_config_set("wr")
    net_connect.send_config_set(" copy tftp://cisco@10.36.50.60/s2t54-ipservicesk9-mz.SPA.152-1.SY6.bin bootdisk:")
    print ("Press enter to confirm ")
    # How can I send a enter command to the shell
```

Sorry I have adjusted the post but I have commented where I need to send the enter key I have already tried print("\n") and I have tried print(" "). Both do not work. Can someone please advise :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to read the enter key into the shell"? Do you mean you need to *send* the enter key to the remote server?

Comment: Please, edit your post and don't use ALL CAPS

Comment: Just send an empty command, and it will end it with the enter key, just like it does after all the other commands.

Comment: You can add an `input('PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE')` This would run the rest of the code after the enter key is pressed. It should work, but ill need more details if this is not what you want. Also, please don't use caps. It looks like your yelling at us.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
`input("Press the enter key to continue.. ")`
Put this wherever you want to confirm or pause.